iTerm2 and zsh standout mode
Running zsh inside iTerms. zsh allows to have parts of the prompt (PS1) printed in standout mode. This is activated using the %S Prompt Expansion Code.
Do I have a chance to influence, how the standout text actually is rendered? From visual inspection, it seems that the rendering simply exhanges background and foreground colour ("reverse video"). Is it also possible to specify a certain RGB colour or, say, italic print, in the iTerm2 preferences, or do I have to change the zsh prompt definition.
Reason is that I work with various terminal profiles. I want to use the identical PS1 definition for all profiles, but on some of them, standout does not look good enough, and I would like to specify the look of the standout property just for one iTerm profile.

I don’t know how much remapping iTerm2 is capable of, but it seems that zsh gets its idea of what “standout” means from the terminfo database, so you could create your own terminal type definition to make it do whatever you like.

Dump the current terminfo definition to a file: infocmp >somefile.

Edit somefile to change the terminal type name, and the codes to start and end standout mode (smso and rmso).

Compile your new terminal type: tic somefile (the compiled version will go into ~/.terminfo/ somewhere).

Set TERM to your new terminal name.



Interesting approach. smso is currently set to \E[7m, which indeed is reverse video. However this would affect all iTerm profiles, and hence it is not what I want.

This would work in just one profile if instead of setting TERM in .zshrc you set "Report terminal type" in the Terminal pane of the profile to the new value.
